# How to get count of distinct rows using groupby in nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have to write the bellow query in nhibernate.

select count(*),Class
  from Student
  group by Class

Help please...

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this?

```
ProjectionList projList = Projections.ProjectionList();
projList.Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Class"));
projList.Add(Projections.Count("Id"));
var result = session.CreateCriteria<Student>()
                            .SetProjection(projList)
                            .List();
```